# Count attendees MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql, count

**Level**
I'm a beginner

I have two tables:

*events*
Details of all the events with a unique eventid per event.

*users*
Lists the details of each attendee with columns eventname1 and eventname2 containing the eventid of the events they are signed up for. (note: a specific eventid could be in either eventname() column e.g. event id 66 could appear in eventname1 for one user and eventname 2 for another)

**What I would Like to Do**
I would like to echo a table with the details of all my events AND include a column (# Attendees) per event which lists the number of users registered for that event.

**What I have so far**

```
   SELECT COUNT( * ) 
    FROM  `users` 
    WHERE  `eventname1` = ( 
    SELECT  `id` 
    FROM  `events` 
    WHERE id =e.g.23 )
```

I have been tring to use this in conjunction with a join but I'm not getting anywhere. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add column details in your question? Question is not readable as of now.

Answer (score 2):

Create 3 tables and store them seperatly and you can count it easily

```
events
event_id, event_name, event_desc, etc_column

users
user_id, username, etc_colun

attendess_table
attendd_id, user_id, event_id, 

select e.event_name, u.username
from attendess_table at
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = at.user_id
INNER JOIN events e ON e.event_id = at.event_id
where u.user_id = 2
```

for counting

```
select count(user_id) from attendess_table where user_id = 2
```

Comment: Even tho this answer suggests some modifications to (I assume) what OP has, it is way better to start working with standards(as @Rafee suggests) rather than struggle with a difficult table structure.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I agree with you Rafee and will try to sort the tables in this fashion next time round.

In the mean time here is what worked for me:

SELECT events., count() 
FROM events left outer join users ON(newevents.id=users.eventname1) OR (events.id=users.eventname2)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,e.name, count(*)   
FROM   users u
left   outer join events e
on     u.id=e.id
group by u.id,u.name,e.name
```